# Rails 3.1 and jquery-ui assets

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, assets

This was asked in another question, but none of the solutions appear to work for me in 3.1rc1.

I'm trying to use the new assets stuff in rails 3.1 - I have the files:

```
./vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css
./vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js
```

I then added:

```
//= require jquery-ui to app/assets/javascripts/application.js
*= require jquery-ui to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

The jquery-ui javascript file loads just fine, but the css file says:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound (couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
     (in /home/xanview2/xancar/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css):6):
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Example of a working setup:

```
    $ cat app/assets/javascripts/application.js

    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery-ui


    $ cat app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

    /*
     *= require vendor
     *
     */


    $ cat vendor/assets/stylesheets/vendor.css

    /*
     *= require_tree ./jquery_ui 
     *
     */

    vendor/assets/ $ tree
     stylesheets
         vendor.css
             jquery_ui
                      jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css
                      ...
     images
        jquery_ui
            ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
            ...
```

Finally run this command:

```
    vendor/assets/images $ ln -s jquery_ui/ images
```

Enjoy your jQuery UI

Comment: Just adding

//= require jquery-ui

solved it for me (as i have "gem 'jquery-rails'" in Gemfile), but  your solution will work if someone have customized jquery-ui (at least I think so).

Comment: Works perfectly for me, have you run the $ ln -s command? If you still have a problem please describe it in a new thread and maybe I or someone else will help you.

Comment: If you do this way, you will need to edit the css and change the images urls, so they get processed thru the pipeline.

Comment: Just a note: you don't need the symlink if using the config.assets.debug option, as the urls in the jquery ui stylesheet will resolve OK

Comment: On Windows since a symlink is not possible, what is the recommended approach?

Comment: Philippe Monnet: The NTFS filesystem does support symlinks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link
Alternatively on windows you can just copy instead of linking.

Comment: @Ram it wasn't for me. I'm getting `require_tree argument must be a directory`

Answer (score 11):

This is a great article to read about Rails 3.1's asset pipeline and jQuery UI: [JQuery-UI css and images, and Rails Asset Pipeline](http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/jquery-ui-css-and-images-and-rails-asset-pipeline/)

Answer (score 8):

You might have more luck with the **[jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)** gem (see [announcement](http://www.solitr.com/blog/2012/02/jquery-ui-rails-gem-for-the-asset-pipeline/)), which packages the jQuery UI JavaScripts, stylesheets and images as assets for you.

Answer (score 6):

This topic comes up a lot, and now that a significant amount of time has passed, things may be different.

In Rails 3.1.2, I found something that works without symbolic links.
Follow the steps above, but **put the images for the theme right next to the jquery-ui-xxx.css file in an images/ folder.** This saved me quite a few headaches.

Yes, this would mean the images would reside in a stylesheets/ folder in vendor/assets, but it works and it is quick to do.

Comment: This was the part that was broken for me. And, couldn't follow the " vendor/assets/images $ ln -s jquery_ui/ images" instruction on Windows. THank you!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the [rails-asset-jqueryui](https://github.com/allen13/rails-asset-jqueryui) gem? It vendors jquery-ui and the standard themes (currently v1.8.16) and makes them available via the asset pipeline. The following example calls for the Smoothness theme.

#### Gemfile:

```
....
gem 'rails-asset-jqueryui'
...
```

#### app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
...
//= require jqueryui
...
```

#### app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
...
= require smoothness
...
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the jquery-ui-rails gem:

application.css

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 */
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that a lot of confusion can be avoided by keeping these library assets out of assets/javascripts and assets/stylesheets dirs, where sprockets et al have some opinions about what should happen.

Say you've downloaded a customized jquery-ui zipfile from the themeroller.  Try this:

1. unpack the zip file into an subdir of an assets dir, something like

   ```
   vendor/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom
   ```
2. in application.rb add:

   ```
   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom').to_s
   ```
3. add manifest files in the usual places:

   vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui.js:

   ```
   //= require_tree ../jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom
   ```

   vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css:

   ```
   *= require_tree ../jquery-ui.1.8.23.custom
   ```
4. in config/environments/production.rb, add (referring to manifest filenames):

   ```
   config.assets.precompile += %w(jquery-ui.js jquery-ui.css)
   ```
5. in views:

   ```
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui' %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui' %>
   ```

Comment: I really like this approach with the exception of #2 not scaling well. I'd love to keep all my vendors in their own structure so upgrade is easy and I don't have to parse out CSS/JS into separate directories. I guess the overarching trend here is someone makes a gem (bootstrap, jquery UI)

Answer (score 0):

if you use this:

https://github.com/carlhoerberg/sprockets-urlrewriter

i believe you can just dump the whole shebang in a directory and require the css file... it will smoothly rewrite the relative urls.

you just have to install the gem and add a config line to application.rb