# jquery ui css with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have added `jquery-ui` with `rails 3.1` but I am not sure where the respected css has to be added. What are necessary steps to be added for this?

Comment: maybe this other SO question would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133818/rails-3-1-and-jquery-ui-assets

Answer (score 0):

We always put them in a folder under`public/stylesheets`

Edit: this is rails2-specific advice...

Comment: Fyi, I am using rails 3.1. So just adding it in `assets/stylesheets` would do?

Comment: hmmm... I'm not as au fait with 3.1 - I know there's this whole 'asset pipeline' thing I'm not as familiar with - so maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best place to put it, but mine works here.

```
app/assets/stylesheets
```