# Rails 3.1 and functionless jQuery-ui images

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets

I found on Google lots of similar problems with jquery-ui and Rails 3.1 - specifically the images from jquery-ui library are not loaded. But I still can't find the right setup for the right functionality.

I followed for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133818/rails-3-1-and-jquery-ui-assets) thread at SO, but I also run the last command `vendor/assets/images $ ln -s jquery_ui/ images`, but unfortunately the images are not loaded. I have this structure of assets in my app:

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

**vendor/assets/images/jquery_ui**

```
list of images
```

**vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js**

```
source of the library jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min
```

**vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery_ui/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css**

```
source of the library jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css
```

**vendor/assets/stylesheets/vendor.css**

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Could anyone any tip, how could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my solution:

into the directory `vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery_ui/` I added the directory `images` with all images of `jquery-ui` library and it already works.

But I still have the feel this is not the optimal solution and I would like to find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

In the SO thread you mentioned is a link to a how-to that's probably the easiest solution with rails 3.1 Here's the link: http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/jquery-ui-css-and-images-and-rails-asset-pipeline/