# What are the jQuery components included in Ruby on Rails 3.1? How do you include the nonincluded?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm assuming Ruby on Rails 3.1 includes just the UI Core components (Core, Widget, Mouse, Position).

**Question Part 1**
Is there somewhere I can confirm this?  I am trying to utilize some of jQuery's other awesome widgets.  The ProgressBar to be exact.
Mainly, I am looking at the list of available widgets located here: http://jqueryui.com/download

**Question Part 2**
If I wanted to add say the jquery.ui.progressbar.js file to my RoR project, do I just add it to the app/assets/javascripts folder and add `<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.progressbar'%>` to my application layout file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find all your answers and much more [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline).

---

First page of the railscast, you see:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree ./public
```

Which means default are `jquery` + `jquery-ui`.

If you want to add more, add them to the manifest or in your view.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the Railscast mainly goes over the 3.1 asset pipeline.  There are no specifics to jQuery.

Comment: you should dig a little more, I've edited my answer to explain further

Comment: take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8409049/230526 it will help you get jquery-ui with themes working