# Why jQuery won't be working?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After I executed this command.
`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Now, jQuery doesn't work anymore:(
It used to work fine until executing the command.

After that, if I type `refreshCount();` in web console command line, it loads function and it works fine.
Just jQuery part(document.ready) doesn't work anymore:(

How can I fix this?

**assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

**views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'delete.js.coffee' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap.js.coffee' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'rails.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'registrations.js.coffee' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'tag-it.js' %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application","http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'reload_count.js' %>
```

**generated HTML**

```
<meta content="6Ee26DJl4R+RoEAP8mHpFaqAQkjAn1TtEFmrWXibfk=" name="csrf-token" />
<script src="/assets/application-hh43uu8e5f7e03b516a031d93d.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/delete-sj4u7032e3f5d3e60ceuu20c3f5792f.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-2b929657252555a21c8fe0915f73.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails-e69b066913d4a1ff967520b8444026d9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/registrations-c8f90781b38ab1267919654197414382.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/tag-it-6bca56a5321c9d3e353987690b24ec8a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="/assets/application-13c063e9f4b98571dfe06a1594565bdf.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/assets/reload_count-0cdf66811b7eaff438be9c8b8cc932bf.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**assets/javascripts/reload_count.js**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        refreshCount();
    });


    function refreshCount() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/messages/refresh_count",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "script",
      });
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message? Can you provide a link or an example that work in the Browser?

Comment: @reporter Thanks. No error message found:(

Comment: It seems `jQuery(document)....` is not being called:(

Comment: Are you sure that jquery is loaded by the browser? you can check that in the console of Chrome or Safari. In Firefox add firebug and check it.

Comment: Are u able to call jQuery(document).... from your browser console without errors?

Comment: try  $(document).ready(function() {... }

Comment: @reporter How can I check? I thought that Rails3 has jQuery as default even if I don't code it.

Comment: @reporter what would be in `...`?

Comment: As I wrote, use the consoles from the browsers or firebug plugin.

Comment: With in {...} put your -sample- code in.

Comment: @reporter I did ` $(document).ready(function() {refreshCount();} ` but it returned ` ({0:({}), context:({}), length:1})`

Comment: @SanthoshK What should I type in my console to check?

Comment: try this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/reporter/FA9Lx/ . Does it work? try the answer of Eli

Comment: @reporter it didn't even work in console. I thought that rails3 own jQuery as default do I need to code that in my `views/layouts/application.html.erb`, though?

Comment: Properbly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237396/how-do-i-add-jquery-ui-to-a-ruby-on-rails-3-1-app can help

Comment: @reporter thanks for showing the link. However, it doesn't look like the solution. What exactly is wrong with my App???

Answer (score 3):

From your generated HTML, I cannot see the included jQuery library. Try to include it by using  google CDN when it's not only make sure that your jQuery is loaded but also has many advantages as compare to normal including script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eli:) You are exactly right. But in my case. I use ruby on rails, and it is a little bit different from the other when implementing jQuery to App. Thanks so much, though:)

Comment: @BillyChan That's what I thought. However it won't be loaded and not working:(

Comment: @MKK, it has been loaded, within application.js. If you check the source of that file you'll find jquery

Comment: @BillyChan In generated html, there is `/assets/application-hh43uu8e5f7e03b516a031d93d.js`. I can clearly see jQuery description in that file. However, my jQuery function won't work:(

Answer (score 1):

You used jQuery methods within your own function but this function is in global namespace. That's why the function won't work.

Try this instead

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    refreshCount();
});
    
    
jQuery.fn.refreshCount = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/messages/refresh_count",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script",
  });
}
```

P.S. You can also open the Network tab in Chrome or Safari debugger to see what messages exchanged with server.

### Add

At first I would suggest you to put all js files in one place, and better in assets using `require some_lib.js`. Move all files using `javascript_include_tag` in header to assets.

Then, you can debug it by disabling other libs.

```
//= require jquery
// <- Add other libs here later
//= reload_count.js
```

If this works, add other libs one by one till you met problem and you'll know which lib caused problem.

Comment: Thanks:) Before doing it, Even `$(document).ready(function() {alert("test");});` in web console won't work. Doesn't it matter?

Comment: @MKK, a dumb but workable method is, disable all other including in head tags and application.js, left jQuery and your custom js file only. If that works, add them one by one.

Comment: Does order or combination matter?

Comment: Sure order does matter. jQuery at the first, custom js at last. Other libs depend on jQuery should go after jQuery. I doubt what "rails.js" is because "jquery_ujs" is Rails built-in lib. Anyway, exclude them all and try yours at first.

Comment: Could you show me an example to put them in correct order? Could you post that as an answer?