# How to remove one extra slash in beginning of resources link in ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, bitnami

I have installed redmine [ project management web application ] using [bitnami](http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine) on CentOS 6.4

Everything is ok but link of resources like css stylesheets are invalid.

For example I have this in main page :

```
<script src="//javascripts/jquery-1.8.3-ui-1.9.2-ujs-2.0.3.js?1379141328" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This link has one more slash in beginning.

What`s the problem?

Comment: You should add jquery with application.js check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237396/how-do-i-add-jquery-ui-to-a-ruby-on-rails-3-1-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133818/rails-3-1-and-jquery-ui-assets?lq=1

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503946/shorthand-http-as-for-script-and-link-tags-anyone-see-use-this-before? Hope this  helps

Answer (score 1):

Links starting with `//` automatically add the correct `uri-scheme`, i.e. `http://` or `https://` depending on the page which requested such a URL.

That is, lets say, `http://google.com` has a script like: `//something.com/app.js`, then `http://something.com/app.js` will be queried. But, if the requested page is `https://google.com`, then `https://something.com/app.js` will be queried.