# Compass: Mixins may only be defined at the root of a document

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am not a ruby developer and I have been using Compass for a good 6 months. I have discovered this problem shown below.

I have read this question and used the top rated answer:
[getting error after ugrading to sass-3.1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616850/getting-error-after-ugrading-to-sass-3-1-8)

Version of Sass: `Sass 3.1.1 (Brainy Betty)`
 (as per suggestion)
Compass version: `Compass 0.12.1 (Alnilam)` (latest)

I run this command: `compass compile --force` when inside project.

```
error sass/screen.scss (Line 3 of _utilities.scss: Mixins may only be defined at the root of a document.)
```

This looks like automatically included file. I definitely can't find it anywhere. My main screen.scss file looks like this:

```
  @import "partials/base";
  @import "blueprint/reset";
  @import "compass/css3";
  @import "sprite/*.png";
  $sprite-layout:vertical;
  $sprite-spacing: 15px;
  @include all-sprite-sprites;
  ....//blah blah blah rest of rules ....
```

Help!

Comment: You get this error when somewhere there is a mixin declaration (@mixin or =mixin_name) that is inside a rule or a function or anything else that is not root. Can you show us the content of partials/base ?

Also the last version of Sass isn't actually 3.1.1 - the website isn't up to date. Look on Rubygems for the latest version : http://rubygems.org/gems/sass