# Insert Ext JS 4.2.1 in the ruby on rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, asset-pipeline

I need to use Ext JS 4.2.1 in a ruby on rails project.

How can I properly insert the Ext Js sdk in rails' asset pipeline,
considering that i need to create a custome theme for the ext js components?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322822/extjs-4-integration-with-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-question) i found a link that describes this for Ext JS 4.1, but it does not apply here, since theming in the new 4.2.1 changed a lot.

My needs are:

- embed the whole Ext JS SDK in the rails project
- embed all the files needed to create a custom theme in Ext JS 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i thought i would write down my solution in case anybody else is wondering.

i put the extjs framework under vendor/assets/javascript, created a new package with sencha cmd tools and then inserted the built theme in application.css

Comment: but this will not include extjs in the asset pipeline, it is recommended to use the extjs4-rails that @nathanvda mentioned or other alternative gems.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is not technically in the pipeline, when i posted this question i was not really familiar with rails.
Still, the gem wouldn't have solved my issue, as i need to be able to create custom javascript files of ext.js through the sencha cmd tools and a custom theme at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [extjs4-rails](https://github.com/pschyska/extjs4-rails) gem.