# active_admin autocomplete with rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, activeadmin

I'm having an issue using the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem with active_admin

I'm using the most recent version of [active_admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) (from git) which now relies on formtastic 2 and I'm using 1.04 of [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)

```
undefined local variable or method `autocomplete_artist_name_records_path' for #<ActiveAdmin::DSL:0x007fde797140d0>
```

It doesn't like the url route I'm providing, any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

## gems

```
gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete', '~> 1.0.4'
```

## records.rb (active_admin)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Record do
  #...
  controller do
    autocomplete :artist, :name#, :full => true
  end

  form do |f|
    f.input :artist_name, :as => :autocomplete, :url => autocomplete_artist_name_records_path
  end
end
```

## routes.rb

```
  resources :records do
    get :autocomplete_artist_name, :on => :collection
  end
```

I also tried this fix which I found somewhere but it didn't change anything including the error

https://gist.github.com/1137340

Answer (score 3):

- Added `admin` namespace in `routes.rb`

  ```
  # Put this line above ActiveAdmin.routes.  Otherwise, you may get this error
  # ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Record with id=autocomplete_artist_name):
  namespace :admin do
    resources :records do
      get :autocomplete_artist_name, :on => :collection
    end
  end

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  ```
- Added these lines in `app/assets/javascript/active_admin.js`

  ```
  //= require jquery
  //= require jquery_ujs
  //= require jquery-ui
  //= require autocomplete-rails
  ```
- In `app/admin/records.rb`, my workaround is using url in string instead of path method

  ```
  form do |f|
    f.input :artist_name, :as => :autocomplete, :url => '/admin/records/autocomplete_artist_name'
    f.buttons
  end
  ```
- Installed jquery css to make the autocomplete suggestion box look nice.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048490/rails-3-1-and-jquery-ui-images).  Then edit `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss` to include the jquery-ui css

Answer (score 1):

The form block is being executed in the scope of ActiveAdmins DSL.

Try rendering the form in a partial to access url helpers.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
   form :partial => "form"
end
```

http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html

Comment: Yeah, I know I could it that way, but it takes all the good AA DSL beauty away from it.